# Paperclip Content Type Validation Failing in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec, paperclip-validation

I'm using Rails 4.0.0 with Paperclip 4.1.1 for attaching mp3 and pdf files.  I'm writing my integration tests in Rspec with Capybara.

I have content type and file name validations in place for both types of files.

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :writeup, presence: true

  has_attached_file :mp3
  validates_attachment :mp3,
    :content_type => { :content_type => "audio/mp3" },
    :file_name => { :matches => [/mp3\Z/] }

  has_attached_file :chords
  validates_attachment :chords,
    :content_type => { :content_type => 'application/pdf' },
    :file_name => { :matches => [/pdf\Z/] }

end
```

I use this in my integration test to fill in attributes for a valid song:

```
def fill_in_valid_song
    fill_in("Title", with: "Valid Song")
    fill_in("Writeup", with: "Description of song")
    attach_file("Mp3", File.join(Rails.root, "/spec/factories/Amazing_Grace.mp3" ))
    attach_file("Chords", File.join(Rails.root, "/spec/factories/FakeChordChart.pdf" ))
  end
```

When I run the integration test for creating a valid song, the pdf file is accepted, but the mp3 file fails the content type validation.

When I follow the same steps myself in the browser, the song uploads successfully without errors.  The model spec also passes using the same file.

I thought the problem might be the capital "M" in "Mp3" when I attach the file, but this is just to specify which file field the attachment goes with.  When I tried changing it to a lowercase "m", the error changed to Capybara not being able to find the field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the content type validation for the mp3 file to be:

```
validates_attachment :mp3,
    :content_type => { :content_type => ["audio/mpeg", "audio/mp3"] },
    :file_name => { :matches => [/mp3\Z/] }
```

The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3003) defined MIME type for mp3 files is `audio/mpeg`.  However some browsers load them as `audio/mp3` which is probably why it works through the browser.

If this doesn't work you could also add `audio/mpeg3` and `audio/x-mpeg-3` as I've seen these used too.